# How can I show on screen the counter of elapsed time, like in real life stopwatches? I'm quite new to programming (C++)

Tags: c++

How can I show on screen the counter of elapsed time? I'd like a real-time counter of elapsed time. If you have any other suggestions or improvements to suggest please tell me because this is very important to me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;
class C{
int ti,tf;
public:
    void start();
    void stop();
    int print();
    } ;
    void C::start(){
    ti=time(0);
    tf=0;
    }
    void C::stop(){
    tf=time(0);
    }
    int C::print(){
    if (tf==0) return time(0)-ti;
    else return tf-ti;}

int main()
{
    char ch;
    C p;
    cout << "i] start\n";
    cout << "f] stop\n";
    cout << "p] print\n";
    cout << "x] exit\n";
     do{
        cout << "option:"; cin >> ch;
        ch=tolower(ch);

        switch(ch){
    case 'i': p.start(); cout << "watch started\n";break;
    case 'f': p.stop(); cout << "watch stopped\n";break;
    case 'p': cout << "time measured: " <<  p.print() << " seconds" << endl ;break;
    case 'x': break;
    default: cout << "invalid option\n";break;
    }
    }while(ch!='x');
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does your code not do what you want? Please explain what is missing / how what it does differs from what you want it to do. And if you have compiler errors, please include them in the question

Comment: Currently your program prints the elapsed time when selecting 'p' . Would you like to have a continuous output of the elapsed time while the watch is running?

Comment: I agree with @idclev463035818. You didn't mentioned the issue you are facing. Also if you are running this code in windows then to implement counter use QueryPerformanceCounter and QueryPerformanceFrequency.

Comment: @sfun Yes, that is exactly what I was looking for. For other users who commented, I'm not facing any issue, I'm just asking how I could do something like that, because I'm new to coding

Comment: It depends on the context. Should the stopwatch display the elapsed time in a GUI? Or do you just want the output to update a line in the terminal? Is the stopwatch meant to be embedded as a part in a larger application or is it a standalone application? Also, on what operating system do you intend on running the application? Depending on your requirements, the answers may be different.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use `std::this_thread::sleep_until(timepoint)`. Presumably you want to print a count in seconds, so you'd repeatedly sleep until `program_start+std::chrono::seconds{i}`.

There's also `std::this_thread::sleep_for(duration)`, which may seem like an easier way to sleep for one second at a time. But that causes your stopwatch to run slightly slower, as the printing itself also takes a little bit of time.